# Exception: unrecognized selector ... when trying to push a view controller on Navigation stack

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to push a view controller on the navigation stack with following code in my buttonPressed method

```
-(IBAction) viewButtonPressed:(id)sender {

PersonDetailViewController *personDetailViewController = [[PersonDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PersonDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:personDetailViewController animated:YES];
[personDetailViewController release];
```

}

I ran the debugger and it throws the exception after followin line is stepped over from above code.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:personDetailViewController animated:YES];
```

This is pretty standard call ... it has worked many times before without any problems. Any idea what am I missing here?
I am stuck at this point and not able to drill down further.

Here are the error messages on the console after running the debugger

`2009-10-30 18:15:11.127 Untitled[6089:20b] * -[NSCFString image]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3050
2009-10-30 18:15:11.129 Untitled[6089:20b] * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFString image]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3050'
2009-10-30 18:15:11.130 Untitled[6089:20b] Stack: (
    807902715,
    2460638779 ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in one of the init methods where I was setting the back button item incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking inside the view lifecycle methods - `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear` etc. - in the `PersonDetailViewController` class for invocations of a method named `image` on some object instance.

You can also try stepping through these methods in an attempt to narrow down where this invocation is made.

Comment: Thanks teabot for the reply ... I was not able to step thru code to figure this out (see anwer below) but just reviewing the code slowly and carefully, I found the problem.